How can I verify method invocations using the equivalent of AssertJ's usingRecursiveComparison
In tests, to verify data objects that do not have hashcode/equals methods, AssertJ has a very nice API:
Assertions.assertThat(result)
    .usingRecursiveComparison()
    .ignoringFields("id")
    .isEqualTo(expected)

For checking that methods have been called, I've always used Mockito:
Mockito.verify(mock, times(2)).method(eq(arg1), eq(arg2));

The situation I'm in now, I want to combine these approaches and use verify, but compare arguments using AssertJ's usingRecursiveComparison, something along these lines:
Mockito.verify(mock, times(2)).method(usingRecursiveComparison(arg1));

Is there any way to achieve this using Mockito + AssertJ, or a different library that does provide this type of API?

Depending on your use case, ArgumentMatchers.refEq might help:
verify(mock, times(2)).method(refEq(arg1, "id"));

or you can leverage AssertJ via ArgumentMatchers.assertArg
verify(mock, times(2)).method(assertArg(arg -> {
    assertThat(arg)
      .usingRecursiveComparison()
      .ignoringFields("id")
      .isEqualTo(arg1)
}));


Yes! From the comments of assertArg: Typically used with Mockito.verify(Object) to execute assertions on parameters passed to the verified method invocation.
